# Using nginx as a transparent MITM forward proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, architecture

I'm wondering if nginx (or squid, etc) can be used to setup a transparent MITM forward proxy in a docker environment (I'm currently using docker compose). I would have 3 "types" of containers - the main web API, a worker and a proxy

- The main API issues tasks to the worker, and any outbound traffic from the worker must go through the proxy.
- The reason for using MITM is to capture and log all http and https traffic - preferably in WARC, but failing that, the logs must capture the socket activity verbatim, byte-for-byte. ie. no agent http header/body parsing, etc
- Some outbound traffic from the worker shall be allowed (AWS, github) but everything else must go through the proxy, or otherwise be blocked
- Additionally, when logging traffic, it must be matched to a specific
  task/worker
- For context, the logged traffic will be used to create
  WARC/WACZ archives with CDXJ indexes, and can be replayed at later date (similar to how web archiving solutions work)

According to this doc: https://gist.github.com/dannvix/5261642

- find the right nginx.conf that will make nginx act as a forwarding proxy
- setup a custom DNS server using dnsmasq, which routes all traffic to the proxy server
- have nginx use self-signed certificates
- install and trust the root certificate in the workers

I'm just not sure how to:

- have the worker container route all traffic through the nginx proxy container
- make this work for any domain (not just api.example.org used in the github gist)
- do all of this via docker compose

### Logging network traffic

I know that nginx might not be the right solution for this.

You can change the log_format, but I'd prefer something that simply logs raw request and response bytes to disk. Is that possible with nginx? I had built a prototype in node.js previously, which takes the Socket (a Duplex stream) and adds additional stream consumers to write the request and response streams to disk, verbatim. It does need a little HTTP-awareness, e.g. when using keepalive connections so it knows when the HTTP transaction has ended (even if the socket remains open)